# StringBuilder и метод trim();

Tags: java, строки

Есть ли аналог метода trim() класса String в классе StringBuilder()

Comment: Список методов класса [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) вы можете посмотреть в документации. Среди них нет `trim()`, так как он там был бы лишним.

Comment: `trimString = builder.toString().trim()`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11094600/how-to-trim-stringbuilders-string

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212928/how-to-trim-a-java-stringbuilder